# How to get a smoother plot, using dashed, dashdotted styles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make this look clearer, but adding [smooth] does not seem to help

The dat.txt has 1000+ data points link to one of the data files : https://pastebin.com/2WSvSBcn

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest}



\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   scale only axis,
   xlabel={Displacement ($mm$)},
   ylabel={Load ($kN$)},
   legend style={legend pos=south east},
]
\addplot[smooth, solid]
   table[x index=3,y index=1] {dat_25n02.txt};
\addplot[smooth, dashed]
   table[x index=3,y index=1] {dat_7a0.txt};
\addplot[smooth, dotted]
   table[x index=3,y index=1] {dat_7w0.txt};
\addplot[smooth, dashdotted]
   table[x index=3,y index=1] {dat_7c0.txt};
\legend{25-N-0,700-A-0,700-W-0,700-C-0}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please also use `begin{filecontents} ... \end{filecontents}` to include a few sample data to reproduce your problem. -e.g. one end of your real data.

Comment: As far as can be concluded from your code fragment, your plot is not possible make more smooth. It is defined by unknown size of tables, and use of `smooth` options in `addplot`.

Comment: Welcome! `smooth` will just join your points with a spline, so if they are not more or less smooth to start with, the result will be bad. Probably you need to do some kind of fitting, instead of smoothing, and probably it's better done *outside* of LaTeX. But as said by @hpekristiansen , we can't help any more without a compilable example with at least something of your data.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Was my first post, was not clear on best practices for posting :)

Edited the post, and included x y data for one of the lines,

seems like there is no way to achieve a clearer figure unless I manipulate the data?